# Resetting the entire Model in single shot in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, model

I am dealing with a Model which I need to reset. Is there any direct way of resetting the entire object in single shot instead of setting each and every property to `nil`? I want to keep this safeguard from any future addition/deletion of keys in the model.

PS: My model is a Swift class with properties.

Comment: What is your model?  An object instance? Data persisted in core data?

Comment: Simply create a new instance of the class and remove all the references to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new instance of your `Model` class. You can even create a static function on your `Model` class that creates and returns a new instance from an existing one.